# jQuery ajax headers parsing issue

Tags: json, jquery

So I'm doing a `GET` with jQuery Ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   headers: {'a':{'t':'text'}, 'b': {'s':'text2'}}
   //...
});
```

According to (*my interpretation of*) the jQuery docs, headers should go in as

```
a: {'t':'text'}
b: {'s':'text2'}
```

Instead, on firebug (and in Fiddler) I see:

```
a: [object Object]  
b: [object Object]
```

Now if I pass it like this:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   headers: {'a':JSON.stringify({t:'text'}), 'b': JSON.stringify({'s':'text2'})}
   //...
});
```

firebug shows them as:

```
a: {'t':'text'}
b: {'s':'text2'}
```

`JSON.stringify` is from Douglas Crockford's [library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

The part I hate about the second approach is that now I need to loop thru my object, and `stringify` child objects. (Note, I have no idea what's inside the object so I cannot do individual `setHeader()`)

**My question is:** Is my understanding incorrect of how `headers` are parsed or am I overlooking something?

Also, I'm looking for the community's inputs on efficiently looping thru the JSON object and `stringify`ing the children.

**Update:** Its pretty clear that my initial understanding was incorrect.

Anyway, any inputs on how to traverse the object and `JSON.stringify` children ***efficiently***?

Comment: `stringify` should recursively stringify an object into JSON actually, are you sure this isn't happening?

Comment: I cannot use `stringify` on top level object. That just creates tons of single alphabet headers.

Comment: Right, I meant on each header individually.  Do you have lots of headers?  If so, are you sure they're truly headers?  Maybe you should be passing these in as parameters.

Comment: No, not too many. A few but they may or may not be present.

Comment: so you can do something like `var passedHeaders = new Object();` and then `passedHeaders.a = JSON.stringify(...);` for each header.  Finally, just use `headers: passedHeaders` in your ajax call.

Comment: I don't know about `passedHeaders.a`. It could be 'a' or 'b' or antyhing.

Comment: you can do `passedHeaders['a']` then

Comment: Why are you using HTTP headers to pass data instead of the querystring? Passing parameters along with GET requests is what the querystring is there for.

Comment: I'm not passing any data in headers. It's session related tokens that shouldn't be visible on querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial understanding was incorrect.  HTTP headers are strings such as:

```
X-Some-Header: Some Value
```

and, as such, you must provide a string as the name and one as the value. Your corrected version where you stringify the children of the top-most object provides just such a string-name/string-value structure.

Comment: That's what jQuery is supposed to do - take my map and translate them to proper key/value pairs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: That is exactly what jQuery is doing.  You gave it a map of string-key to object-values.  The values are appropriately being cast to strings, thus your header values of '[object Object]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to use a JSON Object as your header values, but you need to send it as a string in that case:

```
$.ajax({
   //...
   headers: {'a': "{'t':'text'}", 'b': "{'s':'text2'}"}
   //...
});
```

Comment: That's the thing: I need to now convert them to strings. My initial impression was the jQuery map needs a JSON object which can have other JSON objects as children. Turns out it can be only key/value pairs of `strings`.

Comment: That's right, values must be strings or arrays of strings. See my post. The double quotes make it a string.

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON object.  JSON is a string--a serialized structure using a syntax similar to a subset of JavaScript literals. You provided an object for `headers` which has child objects. You are supposed to be passing an object which has string values. Since you didn't, and since the values are being used where a string is expected, an implicit cast is taking place.

Comment: Oh c'mon man! Should have called JSOL (or JS objects... or just objects)... hate purists! :)

Comment: Heh, well, I'm a purist because the difference matters.  Esp in this case!